# Permission dialog is not shown for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, permissions

[image]I want to download a file using `DownloadManager`. And `DownloadManager` wants to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
I have included the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Furthermore, I try to take this permission on runtime.

onRequestPermissionsResult callback is called immediately after the request permission. The request permission popup didn't display.

However, the value of the `grantResult[0]` on the `onRequestPermissionsResult` is **PERMISSION_DENIED**. But **THE PERMISSION POPUP ISN'T EVEN SHOWN.**

I check the permission like this:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is callback of the permission request:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadFile();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I have tried for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I could take that permission but it didn't work for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Also, I have tried 
[@MetaSnarf's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/1138909) But nothing has changed.

Have you any idea about this situation?

Comment: Have you included the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @deluxe1 yes I have included

Comment: Are you sure `grantResults.length > 1` is correct for a single-permission request?

Comment: It should be `grantResults.length > 0` you can also use  `grantResults.length >= 1`

Comment: I fixed it but it is not problem. The value of grantResult[0] is -1.

Comment: Btw inside isStoragePermissionGranted() you request permission from the user yet you return false no matter if he gives permission or not.

Comment: I know this. but the permission pop-up isn't even shown.

Answer (score 7):

One of your dependency can cause that problem. You can replace permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />
```

Comment: @mertsimsek Tried to debug this for hours... thanks! Do you have an idea how to find out which dependency caused it, or could you explain where something goes wrong? I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Found it - The AppLovin SDK added a maxSdkVersion.. Thanks again! :)